Pointing gem source in new Rails app project
I'm trying to run new Rails 7 app project in offline environment. I have configured npm, yarn, nvm and gem artifactory remote repositories. I have specified in .gemrc file the sources values pointing to artifactory repo. Traditional gem installation works fine:
gem install aaron-test-gem
Fetching aaron-test-gem-0.0.0.gem
Successfully installed aaron-test-gem-0.0.0
Parsing documentation for aaron-test-gem-0.0.0
Installing ri documentation for aaron-test-gem-0.0.0
Done installing documentation for aaron-test-gem after 0 seconds
1 gem installed

but when I try to run new rails app using command:
rails new projapp -d postgresql -j esbuild --css bootstrap

I get an error:
remove  config/initializers/new_framework_defaults_7_1.rb
         run  bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
         run  bundle lock --add-platform=x86_64-linux
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/

Retrying fetcher due to error (2/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Retrying fetcher due to error (3/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Retrying fetcher due to error (4/4): Bundler::HTTPError Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>

Could not fetch specs from https://rubygems.org/ due to underlying error <Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)>
         run  bundle binstubs bundler
Could not find gem 'sprockets-rails' in locally installed gems.
       rails  javascript:install:esbuild
Could not find gem 'sprockets-rails' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  turbo:install stimulus:install
Could not find gem 'sprockets-rails' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
       rails  css:install:bootstrap
Could not find gem 'sprockets-rails' in locally installed gems.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.

Is there any way to run new rails project and point the gem source for that?

Yes, there is an option to create new project using internal gem repository:
bundle config set --global mirror.https://rubygems.org https://mycompany/artifactory/api/gems/gems-remote
